# How to make sub array within a each loop

Tags: ruby, loops, hashmap

I have some text lines like this

```
name carl
age 34
name sean
age 15
```

I have this code

```
lines.each_with_object({}) do |l,r|
     key, value = l.split(' ', 2)
     r[key] = value
end
```

which outputs:

```
{"name"=>"sean", "age"=>"15"}
```

carl is not added, since is overwritten by sean

What I'm looking for is: every line with the `name` make a new elem and put there their values

```
{ "carl" => { "age" => "34" }, "sean" => { "age" => 15 } }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lines.each_slice(2).with_object({}) do |pair, hsh|
  _key, name, attribute, value = pair.flat_map(&:split)
  hsh[name] = { attribute => value }
end
```

This could be one way to go.

**Edit.** If we can have more than one attribute defined under the `name whoever` line, we could something like this:

```
lines.slice_before(/name/).with_object({}) do |clump, hsh|
  _key, name, *rest = *clump.flat_map(&:split)
  hsh[name] = rest.each_slice(2).to_h
end
```

Comment: This works on pairs of two, but what I'm really looking for is, for every pair like `age 34` after `name carl` be inside carl array, when `name sean` is reached everything after it under sean array... Any ideas?

Comment: @greenbandit I added a second solution. This should work when there is at least one attribute under each name.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it:

```rb
hash, current_hash = {}, {}

lines.each do |line|
  key, value = line.split(' ', 2)
  if key == 'name'
    hash[value] = current_hash = {}
  else
    current_hash[key] = value
  end
end
```

`hash` is the result.

Another way with `reduce`:

```rb
current_hash = {}

lines.reduce({}) do |hash, line|
  key, value = line.split(' ', 2)
  if key == 'name'
    hash[value] = current_hash = {}
  else
    current_hash[key] = value
  end
  hash
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I see from a comment that the number of consecutive lines of code that are to be grouped is unknown. Suppose the string were as follows:

```
str = <<BITTER_END
name carl
age 34
iq 95
name sean
age 15
iq 166
BITTER_END
  #=> "name carl\nage 34\niq 95\nname sean\nage 15\niq 166\n"
```

The first step is to determine the number of groups. We can do that as follows:

```
first = str[/\w+/]
  #=> "name"
nbr_groups = str.scan(/\b#{first}\b/).size
  #=> 2
```

`\b` is a "word break" to avoid matching, for example, "rename".

Now let's convert `str` to an array, and while we're at it, get rid of those pesky newline characters:

```
arr = str.lines.map(&:chomp!)
  #=> ["name carl", "age 34", "iq 95",
  #    "name sean", "age 15", "iq 166"]
```

The number of elements per group equals:

```
arr.size/nbr_groups
  #=> 3
```

We are now read to apply [Enumerable#each_slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice):

```
enum = arr.each_slice(arr.size/nbr_groups)
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["name carl", "age 34", "iq 95", "name sean", "age 15",
  #    "iq 166"]:each_slice(3)>
```

We can convert this enumerator to an array to see the (two) elements it will generate:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [["name carl", "age 34", "iq 95"],
  #    ["name sean", "age 15", "iq 166"]]
```

We can now form the desired hash.

```
enum.each_with_object({}) do |(key_str, *val_arr), h|
  h[key_str.split.last] = val_arr.each_with_object({}) do |key_val_str, g|
    key, value = key_val_str.split
    g[key] = value
  end
end
  #=> {"carl"=>{"age"=>"34", "iq"=>"95"}, "sean"=>{"age"=>"15", "iq"=>"166"}}
```

To see what's happening here, first note that another enumerator is being created:

```
enum1 = enum.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: ["name carl", "age 34", "iq 95", "name sean",
  #     "age 15", "iq 166"]:each_slice(3)>:each_with_object({})> 
enum1.to_a
  #=> [[["name carl", "age 34", "iq 95"], {}],
  #    [["name sean", "age 15", "iq 166"], {}]]
```

If you have a close look at the first return value, you will see that `enum1` can be thought of as a "compound enumerator".

The first element of `enum1` is passed to the block<sup>1</sup> and the block variables are assigned to that element using *parallel assignment* (sometimes called *multiple assignment*):

```
(key_str, *val_arr), h = enum1.next
  #=> [["name carl", "age 34", "iq 95"], {}] 
key_str
  #=> "name carl" 
val_arr
  #=> ["age 34", "iq 95"] 
h #=> {}
```

The block calculation is therefore:

```
h["carl"] = ["age 34", "iq 95"].each_with_object({}) do |key_val_str, g|
  key, value = key_val_str.split
  g[key] = value
end
  #=> {"age"=>"34", "iq"=>"95"}
```

I will leave it to the reader to decode the right side of this expression. sean gets the same treatment (except the block variable `h` will equal `{"carl"=>{"age"=>"34", "iq"=>"95"}}`).

Putting this together, we have:

```
arr = str.lines.map(&:chomp!)
arr.each_slice(arr.size/str.scan(/\b#{str[/\w+/]}\b/).size).
    each_with_object({}) do |(key_str, *val_arr), h|
      h[key_str.split.last] = val_arr.each_with_object({}) do |key_val_str, g|
      key, value = key_val_str.split
      g[key] = value
  end
end 
  #=> {"carl"=>{"age"=>"34", "iq"=>"95"}, "sean"=>{"age"=>"15", "iq"=>"166"}}
```

though it might be clearer to keep some of the intermediate variables.

<sup>1 That is done by [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-each), which calls [Array#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each), but that's another story.</sup>